# Scrolling down Google Maps with RSelenium

Tags: r, google-maps, web-scraping, rselenium

I am trying to scroll down the list of places that appear after a Google Maps search using RSelenium

```
library(RSelenium)

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome")

remDr<- rD[["client"]]
remDr$open()

url<- "https://www.google.com/maps?q=bar+in+madrid&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCmLXvyrL7AhWgV6QEHezpCg0Q_AUoAXoECAIQAw"

page<- remDr$navigate(url)
```

I know that the way to scroll to the bottom of a page is by finding an element with `element <- remDr$findElement()` followed by `element$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))`, however I cannot find the element I have to select in order to scroll down. How can this be done?